# Element h4 not allowed as child of element ul in this context?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to debug my footer but I keep getting bugs like
(Element h4 not allowed as child of element ul in this context)

Can anyone explain.
I cant place the HTML because for some reason it does not work.
Probably because there are some mistakes in the code.
Link to my website is 
http://www.timberlife.nl

And then inspect element at the footer of the page.

```
<ul>

<h4 class="footerr">SUPPORT</h4> 
    <br>
<a href="http://timberlife.nl/contact/" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">CONTACT</a> 
    <br>
<a href="http://timberlife.nl/faq/" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">FAQ</a> 
    <br>
<a href="http://timberlife.nl/disclaimer/" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">DISCLAIMER</a> 
    <br>
</ul>
```

It starts with this.

```
<h6 class="text-white copy-text">
```

Many thanks!

Daan

Comment: describe your question properly, add some more related code

Comment: The only valid child of `ul` is `li`.

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz - what do you mean by "just a convention, not having h4 as child of ul"?

Comment: @j08691 i mean , you can still use it

Comment: Your HTML in invalid.

Comment: It's not a convention. It's the technical specification. Put content inside `li` tags.

Comment: yes.. its invalid.. but still you can use it.. validators will throw errorss

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz - I could also write `<div><b><li></p><a><a></div></b>` but it's invalid. As is the OP's code.

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz, I'd love to downvote your comment.

Comment: sigh.. @j08691.. i agree.. just used the wrong word.. **convention**

Comment: @isherwood.. sorry i will just remove the comment.. but I meant the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to HTML5 spec, you can't have header tags as children within a `<ul></ul>`, you should populate it with `<li></li>`, then insert your content within each list like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><h4 class="footerr">SUPPORT</h4></li>
  <li><a href="http://timberlife.nl/contact/" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://timberlife.nl/faq/" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://timberlife.nl/disclaimer/" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">DISCLAIMER</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also noticed you have wrapped entire blocks of content within header tags, try to avoid that as it also leads to invalid html. Use divs rather.

Reference: [w3.org ul element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-ul-element)

Comment: Browsers will try and fix "invalid_ HTML, unless we're talking about XHTML in Strict mode. Trouble is that Google's indexing engine for example also tries to "fix" your invalid HTML and it might decide to do it in a manner that's not really helpful to you. This is especially important when talking about headings.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because your list structure is invalid. All content must be wrapped in `li` tags.

```
<ul>
    <li><h4 class="footerr">SUPPORT</h4></li>
    <li><a href="http://timberlife.nl/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://timberlife.nl/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://timberlife.nl/disclaimer/">DISCLAIMER</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Also, you should use a CSS file (or at least an embedded style tag) rather than inline styles:

```
<style>
    ul li a {color: white;}
</style>
```

Comment: Alright so I should wrap the h4 and the links inside a <li> tag?

Comment: Yes. See my edit. Also, use CSS for styling--not inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use any heading tag within ul then you should place it within li tag because any list inside ul or ol tags can be made only by li tag.
so please try this

```
<li><h4 class="footerr">SUPPORT</h4> </li>
```

This Should work